# Output redirection of cron jobs to an external file

Tags: cron

I have been trying to redirect the output of a cron job to an external file but to no avail. I am using CentOS 7 headless.

I created a small script to execute two commands. The script in itself works.

The goal is to be able to have the output of the two commands running through that script sent to an external folder. 
The script:

```
# #!/bin/bash
/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/bin/nails task --run 1
/opt/McAfee/cma/bin/cmdagent -p
```

The cron job in /etc/cron.d:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/5 * * * * root cd /root && sh epo.sh>>epo.log
```

I have no errors. All seems to work. The output folder has been created but nothing in it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you just tried to change the cron line to: `*/5 * * * * root /root/epo.sh >> /root/epo.log` ? Of course, checking that the `/root/epo.sh` script has execution (`+x`) permissions

Comment: Try running `cd /root && sh epo.sh>>epo.log` in your console, or running a cron of a miminal script that only `echo`es some text, like this `*/5 * * * * root cd /root && sh miSimpleEcho.sh>>epo.log` (don't forget to `chmod +x miSimpleEcho.sh`)